# how to deal with sed if Argument list too long

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Trying to apply the following command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass pass.txt/g" *.ovpn
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
sudo: unable to execute /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

shall i move to `xargs` ?

Comment: "shall i move to xargs?" yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-`xargs` variant using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.ovpn' \
    -exec sed -i 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass pass.txt/g' {} +
```

This would execute your `sed` command on as large batches of filenames as possible (regular files only, no matching directory names etc.), with the filenames matching the given pattern from the current directory (only). It would also cope with potentially strange filenames (spaces, newlines etc.)

The `-maxdepth` option/predicate is not standard but often implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, going with `xargs` is the right way to go.

The simple case is

```
echo *.ovpn | xargs sed -i 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass pass.txt/g'
```

but it only works for files whose names don't contain whitespace. The safe way is

```
printf '%s\0' *.ovpn | xargs -0 sed ...
```

If you don't want to run the whole pipeline as `root`, specify `sudo` before `xargs` or before `sed`.